# How to connect to MongoDB with Java in Netbeans?

Tags: java, mongodb

I already installed MongoDB version 4.4.5. I tried in NetBeans to connect with Java, but I couldn't connect. I added the JAR file, but it is not working.

```
package crudmongodb;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CRUDMongoDB {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Mango db");
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    }
}
```

When I run this code the error code is like below

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package com.mongodb does not exist
```

I added below dependencies also but not working

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Take a look at this [MongoDB Java Driver - Quick Start](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/getting-started/quick-start/) and follow the instructions in it.

Comment: I couldn't can I text you plz send you the screen shot

Comment: You can update your question post with error messages or about the problem you are facing. What do you mean by _"I couldn't..."_?

Comment: In netbeans it doesn't know monogdb when I add the jar file also

Comment: You don't need to add any jar files - you already have defined the dependencies.

Comment: I tried both but not working I don't know

Comment: You can try looking up Netbeans tutorials on using maven dependencies..

Comment: Okay, Thanks sir for helping

Comment: You are trying to import `MongoClient` from the wrong package. Does `import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;` instead of `import com.mongodb.MongoClient;` fix the problem? See the [4.2.x Javadoc for MongoClient](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoClient.html) for full details.

Comment: I tried that also when I move cursor above that its saying  package `com.mongodb.client does not exist` I don't know why maybe my netbeans have problem

Comment: OK, then update your question to show the compiler error when you import from the correct package. As it stands your question clearly shows that you are importing `MongoClient` incorrectly.